# Android: open intent from widget but others are still open

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

Ok so from my simple widget I have a button which opens the main intent of the app.

```
Intent active = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        active.setClassName(Global.appclass, Global.appclass + Global.appEntryPoint); 
        active.putExtra("WidgetInput", mValue);

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,1, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnWidgetValue, actionPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

This intent is see-through and only has an edittext box & ok button on it. 
When someone presses the ok button, I want it to go back to the widget.

But if the application was running before the user pressed the button on the widget then the see-through intent loads over the top of the main application, so you can see the main applications screen in the back ground. how do I close all intents except the one that I am loading.

Hope I explained this ok.

purpose is to supply a input box for a home screen widget, but so it looks like its just over the home screen and nothing else, and it works perfect if the main app is not running in the background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, all I needed to do was use both these flags for the Intent, this makes sure the new intent is the only one running.

```
active.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```